# React.memo Re-Renders my components every time i add a new copy of component

Tags: reactjs, rerender, react.memo

This is my Parent Component , I am using react.memo and usecallback so that i do no un-necessarily re-render component on every button click ,
Instead I am getting these many logs
Rendering Title

Title.js:4 Rendering Title

Count.js:4 Rendering Age

Count.js:4 Rendering Age

Button.js:4 Rendering button -   Increment Age

Button.js:4 Rendering button -   Increment Age

Count.js:4 Rendering Salary

Count.js:4 Rendering Salary

Button.js:4 Rendering button -  Increment Salary

Button.js:4 Rendering button -  Increment Salary

```
import React, { useCallback, useState } from 'react';
import Title from './Title';
import Count from './Count';
import Button from './Button';

function ParentComponent() {
  const [age, setAge] = useState(25);
  const [salary, setSalary] = useState(50000);

  const incrementAge = useCallback(() => {
    setAge(age + 1);
  }, [age]);

  const incrementSalary = useCallback(() => {
    setSalary(salary + 1000);
  }, [salary]);

  return (
    <>
      <Title />
      <Count text="Age" count={age} />
      <Button handleClick={incrementAge}>Increment Age</Button>
      <Count text="Salary" count={salary} />
      <Button handleClick={incrementSalary}>Increment Salary</Button>
    </>
  );
}

export default ParentComponent;
```

Titlle.js

```
import React from 'react';

function Title() {
  console.log("Rendering Title");
  return (
    <div>Title</div>
  );
}

export default React.memo(Title);
```

Count.js

```
import React from 'react';

function Count({ text, count }) {
  console.log(`Rendering ${text}`);
  return (
    <div>{text} - {count}</div>
  );
}

export default React.memo(Count);
```

Button.js

```
import React from 'react'
//children -- props.children -- Increment age -- 
function Button({handleClick , children}) {
  console.log('Rendering button - ', children)
    return (
    <button onClick={handleClick}>{children}</button>
  )
}

export default React.memo(Button);
```

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure that your component is wrapped around ***StrictMode***. Usually strict mode causes this behaviour in our react apps. If so, please remove it and try again.

[image]

Comment: oh i see thanks you

Comment: Mark the response as answer if the issue is resolved.